# onClick handler is applying on all elements after map

Tags: reactjs

I have the following data:

```
export const Bookings = ({ booking, selectedBookings }) => {
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false)

const handleSelect = (data) => {
    selectedBookings(data)
  }

{booking.map(data => (
        <div
          key={nanoid()}
          className={selected ? styles.selectedDescription : styles.NonSelectedDescription}
           onClick={() => {
             handleSelect(data.name); // when I add this it does not trigger the style toggling
            setSelected(!selected) // if I keep only this handler it works but for all childrens
          }}
        >
          {description}
        </div>
```

In this code I want to send data to parent component and apply a specific styles when the booking is clicked, BUT I have 2 issues:

1- when I remove the `handleSelect(data.name)` the styles apply on whole childrens and not one single chidren.

2- when I add the `handleSelect(data.name)` handler the styles does not work at all, but the handler send the data to the parent

So is there any problem here?

Comment: You only have ONE `selected` value, but you have multiple bookings. You need to track the selected state for each individual booking. You can do this by storing an array of selected booleans, one for each booking and changing those. Or move the booking into its own component that has its own internal state which tracks whether it's selected or not. Also I don't know what `nanoid()` does but if it returns a new random value each time it's called then having `key={nanoid()}` is a bad idea, because keys are supposed to be unique *and persistent*. This will run the nanoid function every render

Answer (score 0):

You need to store different `selected` boolean for all bookings;

Try something like below:-

1. Change `selected` state to object:-

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState({})
```

2. Change `handleSelect` like below:-

```
const handleSelect = (dataName) => {
    setSelected({...selected, selected[dataName]: !selected[dataName]});
  }
```

3. Change `className` in `div` like below:-

```
{booking.map(data => (
  <div
    key={nanoid()}
    className={selected[data.name] ? styles.selectedDescription : styles.NonSelectedDescription}
    onClick={() => { handleSelect(data.name); }} 
   >
     {description}
   </div>
))}
```

Note:- All booking name should be unique, If they are not unique you need to pass unique value in `handleSelect` function.